# Find value of serie with complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find the value of the following serie:

$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{(\pi i)^n}{n!}$

Our professor didn't show us how to do that with complex numbers. 
$\frac{1}{2^n}$ gets smaller and smaller as n increases.
When I expand $\frac{(\pi i)^n}{n!}$, I get
$1+\pi i -\pi^2/2- i \pi^3/6 + \pi^4/24+ i\pi^5/120 - \pi^6/720 - ... $

As expected, the sign changes every two times because of the imaginary number, but I don't really see what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $e^z=\sum \frac {z^n}{n!}$ even for complex $z$.

Comment: If I distribute the sum, I get 2 + e^(pi*i), because 1/2^n can be rewritten as (1/2)^n which is a geometric sum and converges to 2. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.